# Scheduling algorithm with waiting time and priority

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

I have gone through a list of scheduling algorithms and their implementation, however couldn't find any reference to implement an algorithm that solves the following problem.

Given an array of processes having n process, the i'th  process being represented by:

***Arrival[i]*** representing its arrival time,

***Depart[i]*** representing the time when a process will be terminated (processed or unprocessed doesn't matter) and

***Time[i]*** representing the time required to serve the process, and

***Preferred[i]*** representing a Boolean value (true if that process is preferred, false otherwise)

We need to schedule the processes to maximize processing of preferred processes.

Only a single process can be served at a time, and if a process departs before its completion its said to be unprocessed.  Otherwise, once started, a process cannot be suspended or interrupted.

The criteria for "best" solution are, in order:

1. Most preferred processes served.
2. Most non-preferred processes served
3. Least total processing time.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: No burst time given?

Comment: I don't think classical computation processes have such attributes, thus no schedulers implemented. It looks more like queueing theory exercise.

Comment: @VidorVistrom added the attribute which was missing.

Comment: Seems to me like the standard highest priority first with just an added constraint of departure time

Comment: @Ashutosh: (A) your evaluation says "in case of a tie", but I don't see any metric that applies yet.  Just what is tied?  (B) if a process departs before completion, can it be restarted?  If so, at what point do we restart?  This greatly affects the solution: if we have to start over, then starting a process we'll have to interrupt makes no sense at all, we can remove those from consideration.  That would reduce the problem to a lightly-augmented interval problem.

Comment: @Prune 
(A) By tie I mean the scenario where multiple solutions exist, each serving equal number of preferred processes. 
(B) If a process departs, then it can't be restarted. A process can be served between it's arrival time and departure time only.

Comment: @Ashutosh: Thanks; I have to read more closely on Friday evening.  :-)  Those answers are in the original posting.  I was a little confused by the over-stipulation in tiebreaker #1: if multiple solutions are tied for quantity of preferred processes, it's redundant to include those in the tiebreaker.  The description problem is the instructor's error, not yours.

Comment: @Ashutosh: Can a process be started, interrupted, and picked up where we left off?

Comment: For instance, P1 arrives at time 0, departs at 10, and requires 5 units of time.  P2 arrives at time 4, departs at 8, and requires 4 units of time.  Can we run them both?  P1[4 units], then P2[4 units], and then the last 1 unit of P1.

Comment: @Prune , No the process has to either be completed in one go, or discarded.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your best solution will be a simple back-tracking algorithm -- try all possibilities, evaluating each with a score of "missed points": minimize the quantity of preferred processes you did *not* complete.

First, a little pre-processing:

- Partition the list into to lists, preferred and not.
- Sort each list by arrival time.
- For each process, subtract the processing time from the departure time; this yields "latest start time", a more useful figure for us.

Now, just do the classic try-everything recursion:

```
Base Case:
    If process list is empty, move to handling non-preferred processes in a similar function.

Case 1: Serve the first process `P` on the list.
    skipped [remains unchanged]
    new_served_list = served_list + P (append)
    new_start = current start time + `Time(P)`
    new_total = total processing time + `Time(P)`
    // remove processes whose latest start time will be passed:
    new_proc_list = proc_list - {any process with `latest_start(P) < start_time`}.
    Recur on (new_start, new_total, new_served_list, new_proc_list)
    save `result_1`

Case 2: *Don't* serve the first process.
    new_skipped = skipped + 1
    new_proc_list = proc_list - `P`.
    recur on (start, total, served_list, new_proc_list)
    save `result_2

Compare result_1 and result_2; return the better one.
```

You still need a similar function for the non-preferred processes -- but that one will have to fit processes into the interstices of preferred processes.  I'll leave that extension as an exercise for the student.  :-)

Note that it breaks down to a lot of tiny problems, one for each open interval.